# Update all rows with a column value matching a column in another table

Tags: mysql

Imagine two tables with columns of A, B, C and D, E, F respectively.

Table #1 has series of rows in column B with identical values, and values in column C have several matches in column F.

This is due to table #1 having 'Groups' and each Group can have 'sub groups'.

Column 'C' is the 'Sub Group Id'.

I need to fill table #1 from table #2:

- Column A is assigned the value from column D, if column C matches F.
- All values from Column B, that were the same, are assigned the value from column E, if their column A is changed.

Say, I have

Table A:

```
 A    B    C 
null AAA  123
null AAA  321
null ABA  789
```

Where column 'C' is a 'sub group id'.

Table B:

```
 D    E    F
 1   KFA  123
 2   DQD  345
 3   BHD  567
```

Now, if one 'sub group id' is updated with values then all the rows in that 'Group' should be updated with the same value.

After updating, I should get

```
 A    B    C 
 1   KFA  123
 1   KFA  321
null ABA  789
```

Basically, the 1st table is grouped, and I need to update it in groups, changing their A and B columns to the respective values from table #2, which I can't quite get right for a while. I looked at many Stack Overflow related questions but couldn't find one that does what I need. My earlier attempts were in line of

```
update A join B on
  A.C=B.F
set
 A.A=B.D,
 A.B=B.E;
```

with some variations.

EDIT: Sorry for late response, got logged out and then forgot my password. This question can be ignored, as I don't have to do this anymore.

Comment: Can we see the nearly right attempt? And what's your PRIMARY KEY in both instances.

Comment: I don't understand the second row result

Comment: Edited my current attempt. There are no primary keys in both tables even tho the second table (the actual one, not the simplified in my example) should have it, but it's from another guy, so I just have to work with what I have. :(

Comment: Assuming you're matching rows in table a/1 with rows in table b/2 on columns f/c then I can't see anything wrong with your latest attempt.

Comment: The original table in the example is split into two groups, AAA and ABA; AAA has two "subkeys", 123 and 321. 123 matches a row in table two column F, so its group AAA gets updated such so all its rows in column A get assigned the value of the matched column D, and all its rows in column B are assigned the of the matched column E.

Comment: It doesn't update all rows in the group. Only the row with where the condition is met have the update to apply.

Comment: I see - so just join table2 twice - oh, hang on, it's more complicated than that...

Comment: Now you need a PRIMARY KEY on both tables. Fix that, then get back to us.

Comment: imo, you either need 1) A 'group' to 'sub group' table, or 2) a 'group id column' maybe called 'G', on table #1? And label column 'F' as 'SG'  and column 'C' as 'SG' instead?